# HIVE : NoSuchMethodError: org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()I

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, hive, beeline

I have been trying to install hive on windows. I have 64 bit windows 8 on which HADOOP and SPARK are running. I have

```
1.HADOOP_HOME
2.HIVE_HOME
3.SPARK_HOME
4.Platform
5.PATH
```

all these variables set up on my system. Also, I was getting these error before

```
Missing Hive Execution Jar: C:\hadoop1\hadoop-2.7.2\apache-hive-1.2.1-bin/lib/hive-exec-*.jar
```

I solved these error by editing the Hive file inside bin folder of HIVE. These errors are because of the forward slash"/" in environment variables in HIVE file. I replace them with "\" and those errors are gone. But now I am facing another problem. I am getting these error

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/lib/spark-assembly-1.6.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/C:/hadoop2.7/hadoop-2.7.1/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.10.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
Beeline version 1.6.1 by Apache Hive
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.fusesource.jansi.internal.Kernel32.GetConsoleOutputCP()I
    at jline.WindowsTerminal.getConsoleOutputCodepage(WindowsTerminal.java:293)
    at jline.WindowsTerminal.getOutputEncoding(WindowsTerminal.java:186)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:230)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:221)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.<init>(ConsoleReader.java:209)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.getConsoleReader(BeeLine.java:834)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.begin(BeeLine.java:770)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.mainWithInputRedirection(BeeLine.java:484)
    at org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine.main(BeeLine.java:467)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

I have searched alot on these. Also I have posted these question on HIVE User mailing List but got no response. Please help me with this.

Comment: That error usually means that the source was compiled against a version of a library that contained the method but is deployed with a different version that does not contain the method, or where the method has a different signature.  Make sure the libraries installed in your deployment environment match the required versions.

Comment: Hi @JimGarrison, thanks for replying I have read the installation guide and according to that I have JAVA 1.7, HADOOP 2.7 and Apache hive 1.2.1 but I still got this error?

Comment: Hive/Hadoop are outside my areas of expertise. I'm just telling you what typically causes that type of error -- a dependency version problem.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the steps I executed to solve this:

1. Install the Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 Redistribuable add-on (not the latest, not the SP1...)
2. Download the jline-2.12.jar (from any maven repository site) and put it into your %SPARK_HOME%\lib directory
3. I assume you already have a hadoop client correctly configured with HADOOP_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR y YARN_CONF_DIR defined. You need SPARK_HOME to be defined, too
4. ***In case you're using a Cloudera 5.5+ cluster***, download the Cloudera JDBC Driver for Hive (last version available) and unzip the Cloudera_Hive41* archive into %HADOOP_HOME$\share\hadoop\hive (this directory doesn't exist, you need to create it). If you're not using Cloudera, you can forget this point.
5. Create a new beeline batch script :

> ```
> @echo off
> setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
>
> Rem Hive Classpath Settings ONLY IF YOU'RE USING CLOUDERA
> set HIVE_CLOUDERA_DRIVER_DIR=%HADOOP_HOME%\share\hadoop\hive
> set HIVE_CLASSPATH=
> for /R %HIVE_CLOUDERA_DRIVER_DIR% %%a in (*.jar) do (
>   set HIVE_CLASSPATH=!HIVE_CLASSPATH!;%%a
> )
> set HIVE_CLASSPATH=!HIVE_CLASSPATH!
> Rem IF YOU'RE NOT USING CLOUDERA YOU CAN SKIP THE HIVE_CLASSPATH_STUFF
>
> Rem Spark Classpath Settings
> set SPARK_CLASSPATH=
> for /R %SPARK_HOME%/lib %%a in (*.jar) do (
>   set SPARK_CLASSPATH=!SPARK_CLASSPATH!;%%a
> )
> set SPARK_CLASSPATH=!SPARK_CLASSPATH!
>
> Rem Hadoop classpath
> set HADOOP_CLASSPATH=%HADOOP_CONF_DIR%\;%YARN_CONF_DIR%\\
>
> Rem Java Virtual Machine Options
> set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms1g -Xmx1g 
>
> Rem Execute Beeline
> java -cp "%HIVE_CLASSPATH%;%SPARK_CLASSPATH%;%HADOOP_CLASSPATH%" %JAVA_OPTIONS% org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine %*
> ```

You can execute beeline throw this new script without any issue.